# Odoo 10 use custom field contents

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

Probably noob question, but I find it hard to wrap my head around this:

I can create custom field (boolean) on `Project` model by adding field and modifying the form view:

```
<field name="x_project_urgent"/>
```

This works well as expected. 
Now, I want to render some html based on the value of this field in my kanban view:

[image: where I want to have conditional information]
[image]

The code I would like could read something like this(but obviously this doesn't work):

```
<div attrs="{'invisible': [('x_project_urgent', '=', True)]}">
  URGENT
</div>
```

so `x_project_urgent` is my boolean custom field. If in this 'kanban' view i use `<field>` tag, it will show the True/False . The thing is I just want to have some simple logic and not just display True/False .

I have no idea how to access project's x_project_urgent custom attribute and write any 'logic' code in the view.

```
project.x_project_urgent
```

gives me error: `Error: Unknown field project.x_project_urgent in`

My guess is that this is possible but I'm such a noob with odoo that I dont even know where to find it in the documentation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITS :

When i showed the value of the x_project_urgent booelan field in kanban look at the result:

```
<div class="o_primary">
    <span><t t-esc="record.name.value"/></span>
    <span t-field="record.x_project_urgent"/>
    <span t-esc="record.x_project_urgent"/>
    <span t-esc="record.x_project_urgent.value"/>
</div>
```

[image]

AND this is how you should do it:

```
<t t-if="record.x_project_urgent.value">
    <div> URGENT</div>
</t>
```

[image]

Comment: I have simply added custom field using the GUI. All I need is to be able to use it in the view wherever my `project` is referenced like in the kanban view. I would imagine with odoo this should be possible without writing python code, no?

Comment: i edited my answer you can create any type of field and add it to you model even compute fields !! thank you for your question again

Comment: thanks for taking time. When I asked question I have already added the field and extended the form in the way you're describing. What I'm yet missing is using the data in the views where I can not use `<filed>` tag. Let me clarify my question

Comment: i think this is what you want

Comment: Yes, this is what I want, and I actually tried this before. the problem is - when I do this - `record.x_project_urgent` seems to return false regardless of what the boolean is set to...

Comment: didn't know that too i learned a lot from your question it was fun ^^

Comment: i said that t-field didn't show anything because i tested it ^^

Comment: @Charif - really appreciate your support. I must be doing something wrong, when I use other fields, then my boolean - it seems to display the value. The boolean field,  not so much. I even recreated it with a different name but, as much as it is visible when I use `<field>` tag, in the syntax above, it does not show up. When I write `.value` I get error: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'dict['record'].x_project_urgent.value')`

Comment: ohh did you add the field to the list of field in the kanban view ? my friend i'm learning about adoo and finding solution for other people is a very good way but i don't have this error

Comment: No! I think this is is my friend! Let me check.

Comment: Bingo! That worked, I feel silly for missing this, not that I look at this template - I should have looked at this list of fields

Comment: thank you if you want we can keep in tache in facebook or linkind we may help each others

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141954/discussion-between-lukasz-muzyka-and-cherif-odoo).